# How to send a list of array from chrome extension to my python app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to send a list of arrays from chrome extension to my native python app using native messaging api.

## background_script.js

```
port = window.browser.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
port.postMessage(request.attributes);
```

## my_app.py

```
text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.read(4)
text_length = struct.unpack('i', bytes(text_length_bytes, 'utf-8'))[0]
text = sys.stdin.read(text_length)
```

Connection between chrome extension, and native python app stops when i send a list of arrays as attribute in post message, but it works when i give a string as an attribute.

Comment: Look at what's actually been sent using console.log(JSON.stringify(request.attributes))

Comment: It is sending list of lists

Comment: The example linked in the documentation is `text = sys.stdin.read(text_length).decode('utf-8')` - your code is missing the decode call.

Comment: I have done decoding here

text_length = struct.unpack('i', bytes(text_length_bytes, 'utf-8'))[0]

Comment: You've only decoded the length.

Comment: Even after adding text = sys.stdin.read(text_length).decode('utf-8') my app crashes with message 
""" Unchecked runtime.lastError: Native host has exited. """

Comment: There's probably something else wrong. Use the example app linked in the documentation as is, and first make sure it works on your computer, then modify it to accommodate your needs.

Comment: Yes, i have tried that app and i have also created my own app with it, and I am able to send the data in form of string using  ''' port.postMessage(JSON.stringify(request.attributes)); ''' but I want to send it as an object.